# Modify query with regex?

Tags: c#, regex

```
string strModifiedQuery  = "SELECT TAB1.Key
FROM TAB1 IN 'C:\TEST\SAMPLE\HELLO.mdb'
ORDER BY TAB1.Key;"
```

I want to modify the above query as follows notice the **[HELLO]**

```
string strModifiedQuery  = "SELECT TAB1.Key
FROM [HELLO].TAB1
ORDER BY TAB1.Key;"
```

I tried using the following regular expression; but couldn't arrive at the correct one.

```
string pattern3 = @"(?i)'\w\:\\\w+\\\w+\\\w+.(mdb|accdb)'";
strModifiedQuery = Regex.Replace(strModifiedQuery, pattern3, @"[$0]");
```

Comment: What if you solve it without regular expressions (as soon as you cannot handle it easily)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  (?=.*?\\)(?:.*?\s(.*?))\s*IN.*\\(.*?)\.(?:mdb|accdb).*?\n
```

Replacement to be done:

```
  FROM [$2].$1\n
```

See demo:

http://regex101.com/r/nR2kU8/1

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to the below code,

```
string strModifiedQuery  = @"SELECT TAB1.Key
FROM TAB1 IN 'C:\TEST\SAMPLE\HELLO.mdb'
ORDER BY TAB1.Key;";
string result = Regex.Replace(strModifiedQuery, @"(?i)(?s)(.*?)\S+\s*\S+\s*'\w:\\\w+\\\w+\\(\w+)\.(?:mdb|accdb)'", "$1[$2].TAB1");
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

`(?i)` turn on the case insensitive mode and the DOTALL modifier `(?s)` makes the dot in the regex to match also a newline character. The above regex would match the two words which are just before  the path upto the line end and  it also captures the word characters which was just before to the string `.mdb`. In the replacement part, captured group was referenced back to get the desired result.

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/WYWVvy)

Try the below code if you don't want to geive the string `TAB1` explicitly,

```
string result = Regex.Replace(strModifiedQuery, @"(?i)(?s)(.*?(\S+)\.key.*?)\S+\s*\S+\s*'\w:\\\w+\\\w+\\(\w+)\.(?:mdb|accdb)'", "$1[$3].$2");
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/7HhV9z)